# how to append Any type data to string in swift

Tags: swift, append

I need to call get api, for this I need to append parameters in the api calling. but my problem is that I am getting that paramters in the response of previous view api. 
Now I have this dictionary in response

```
Employee Detail Info {
"business_unit_3" = "South Europe";
"currency_type" = TRY;
"date_of_joining" = "01-Nov-10";
desig = "KEY ACCOUNT MANAGER";
email = "try-employee-16@aw.com";
"emp_salary_status" = 1;
"final_salary" = "241455.28";
"first_approver" = "TRY-Employee-10@aw.com";
"fourth_approver" = "TRY-Employee-5@aw.com";
grade = 3;
id = 134;
"increment_applied_on_salary" = "227788.00";
"last_action_by" = "TRY-Employee-10@aw.com";
"last_manager_name" = "TRY-Employee-10";
level = 3A;
"manager_discretions" = "6.00";
"manager_emailid" = "TRY-Employee-10@aw.com";
"market_salary" = "0.00";
name = "TRY-Employee-16";
"performance_cycle_name" = AW;
"performance_rating" = "Exceeds Results";
"req_status" = 1;
"rule_id" = 1;
"rule_name" = "AW Sal";
"rule_staus" = 6;
"second_approver" = "TRY-Employee-3@aw.com";
"tbl_pk_id" = 133;
"third_approver" = "TRY-Employee-5@aw.com";
"upload_id" = 1;
```

}

I need to get id , rule id and upload id from this dictionary and append these values in the call of my second api. I am not sure what type of data I'll get in it so I have taken "Any"

for this I write my code

```
    func getSalaryReviewDetailApi()
    {


  var userID:Any = 0
        var ruleID :Any = 0
        var uploadID :Any = 0

        // Get paramters from dict
        if (self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "id") != nil){
            userID = self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "id") as Any
        }

        if (self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "rule_id") != nil){
            ruleID = self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "rule_id") as Any
        }

        if(self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "upload_id") != nil){
            uploadID = self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "upload_id") as Any
        }

        let apiToContact = ApiConstants.UrlBase+ApiConstants.EndPointGetSalaryReviewDetail+"\(userID)/\(ruleID)/\(uploadID)"        
        print("Api Calling \(apiToContact)")

        }
```

but in printing of it

I m getting this

```
 https://test.company.in/user-portal/api/team/employeeincrement/Optional(134)/Optional(1)/Optional(1)
```

how to remove optional from here and get acutal value of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

```
let apiToContact = ApiConstants.UrlBase+ApiConstants.EndPointGetSalaryReviewDetail+"\(userID!)/\(ruleID!)/\(uploadID!)"
```

**UPDATE**

```
if (self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "id") != nil){
    userID = self.dictEmployeeDetail.object(forKey: "id") as Int
}
```

alternative way to do this,

```
if (self.dictEmployeeDetail["id"] != nil){
    userID = self.dictEmployeeDetail["id"] as Int
}
```

and please read about the [Optionals in Swift](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm)

Comment: Getting this warning 
Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Any'
I tried it but not work

Comment: do not cast it to Any, convert them to Int

Comment: Getting crash when put Int in the place of Any.

Comment: var userID:Any = 0 must be Int not Any, like this   var userID:Int = 0